# Laravel-Livewire: Form method converted to get after pagination

Tags: jquery, laravel, forms, pagination, laravel-livewire

**Introduction context:** 
The project I am working on has been a long-running project. For this reason, it has been set up with Bootstrap and JQuery. As time has progressed, there has been feedback on certain features. One of these was filtering in a modal pop-up, on a table that worked using ajax to get HTML rows. This felt clunky and hard to maintain, so I decided that Livewire would work really well in this scenario. After a lot of head-scratching, I ended up with a great working result. Pagination, filtering, etc., it all works. As a result, I had to refactor some other parts within the table too.

**The issue:** 
Within the table, there are actions to change the state of a model (that get handled in a controller). As per the design, these actions require confirmation via a Bootstrap modal. The confirm button simply triggers a submit on the targeted form. Upon initial page load, this works perfectly. However, after switching pages, the same action results in a 404. I couldn't see anything crazy within the network request. It feels like Livewire is manipulating the request but I couldn't find out what or why. After more testing (with delete routes as well), it turns out that the request is made as `get` after pagination. A delete route ends up on the show page. The 404 result is simply as the route does not exist as the `get` variant.

**Reproduce:**

1. Have a component with pagination.
2. Have a form within the component, with the method `post`.
3. Have a button
4. Upon button click, submit the form with JQuery
5. ??? > profit
6. Go back, paginate, click again
7. ??? > 404

**Code:** 
*Within component:*

```html
<form id="post-form" method="post" action="{{ route('example-post-route', compact('model')) }}">
    @csrf
    <input type="hidden" name="status" value="new">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data-confirm data-target="#post-form">
        Set status new
    </a>
</form>
```

*Script:*

```js
$(document).on('click', '[data-confirm]', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let target = $(this).data(target);

    // Target bootstrap modal, bind click event to confirm
    $('#confirmation-modal').modal('show');
    $('#confirmation-modal-confirm').click(function () {
        $(target).submit();
    });
});
```

*Controller:*

```php
public function updateStatus(Request $request, $model) 
{
    $status = $request->input('status');

    $model->update(['status' => $status]);

    return redirect()->route('example-index-route')->with('success', 'Model status updated');
}
```

**Afterword:** 
I did try to submit a Livewire form (`wire:submit.prevent="updateStatus"`), but instead it submitted to the current page URL with method `post`. Solutions/suggestions are very welcome. I might end up refactoring the modal to a Livewire component as I did with the filters so I can ensure the submits are consistent. I didn't want to do this, to save time (since I'd have to build a Livewire modal with Bootstrap that is dynamic...), but this way it seems like it will only cost me more time.

**Context:** 
Livewire version: [2.4.4] 
Laravel version: [7.30.4] 
Alpine version: [2.8.2] (Not used within this context, however) 
Browser: [Firefox]